# Machine Learning Gradient descent python implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

#### Problem

I have written this code, but this is giving errors:

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
>
> ```
> t2_temp = sum(x*(y_temp - y))
> ```
>
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>
> ```
> t1_temp =  sum(y_temp - y)
> ```

Should I use feature scaling or is there something wrong in my code?

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gradient_descent(x,y,t1,t2,repeat,alpha):
    n = x.size
    for i in range(repeat):
        y_temp = x*t2 + t1
        t1_temp =  sum(y_temp - y)
        t2_temp = sum(x*(y_temp - y))
        t1 = t1 - alpha * (t1_temp/n)
        t2 = t2 - alpha * (t2_temp/n)

    return [t1,t2]


d = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

x = d['GrLivArea']
y = d['SalePrice']

x = (np.array(x.values))
y = (np.array(y.values))


alpha = 0.047
repeat = 3000

theta = [1.23154644,1.654132398]

tt = gradient_descent(x,y,theta[0],theta[1],repeat,alpha)

print("FINISH")
```

Comment: Try scaling your values in the columns by a factor, and run it. Most likely the column values are too big, causing overflow.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine; it is `x` and `y` that are too large. You can perform standardisation or some other form of scaling.

Comment: I am applying but for testing data i am getting wrong output. Feature scaling will give the value of theta1 and theta2 which we can use as it is in our equation or testing data should also be processed further ?

Comment: After getting value of theta1 and theta2 i am putting it into equation and i am checking my test data , that is basically plot size , so the output which should be price is also scaled down.

Comment: If you have not scaled your `y` values, then the scaling of `x` should only affect the coefficients, not the results. Have your coefficients converged? (check if the gradients are near 0)

Comment: Yes i have scaled both x and y and my coefficients are also converging both are near 0.

Comment: @K.Bakshi well, in that case you would need to scale `y` up again.

Comment: Here x is my input and y is my output , so in which manner i should scale them so that i get correct output for testing data. Can i bring the values of both x and y between range 0 to 1. Originally value of x is between 1000 to 5000 and value of y is between 2000000 to 9000000.